# Dockerfile for R-3.4.4, How to reduce the time of docker build, it takes at least 30 min

Tags: r, docker, docker-image

In order to reduce the size of my Docker image for R, earlier it was 2G. I have written the installation and all the process and removing of the packages in one layer, that helps in reducing the image size. But it takes at-least 30 min to build the docker image between 30 min to 45 min. How to reduce the time

Dockerfile

```
FROM centos
LABEL maintainer="admin.squad@xyz.com" \
  version="2.0" \
  project="xyz-R"
#EXPOSE 9988
ARG APP_HOME="/opt/deployment"
ARG PROJECT_NAME="xyz-R"
ENV LANG en_US.UTF-8
ENV APP_HOME=${APP_HOME} \
PROJECT_NAME=${PROJECT_NAME} \
PROJECT_HOME=${APP_HOME}/${PROJECT_NAME}

#RUN yum makecache
RUN yum install -y wget centos-release-scl bzip2-devel openssl- 
devel cyrus-sasl-devel libxml2-devel && \
yum install -y devtoolset-6 && \
source scl_source enable devtoolset-6 && \
export PATH=/opt/rh/devtoolset-6/root/bin:$PATH && \
rm -rf /var/cache/yum && \
mkdir packages1; cd packages1; wget -qO- https://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/libpng/zlib/1.2.8/zlib-1.2.8.tar.gz | tar zvx && \
cd zlib-1.2.8; ./configure; make; make install; cd .. && \
pwd && \
wget -qO- http://downloads.sourceforge.net/pcre/pcre-8.35.tar.gz | tar xzv && \
cd pcre-8.35; pwd; ./configure; make; make install; cd .. && \
wget -qO- http://tukaani.org/xz/xz-5.2.2.tar.gz | tar xzv && \
cd xz-5.2.2; ./configure; make; make install; cd .. && \
wget -qO- https://curl.haxx.se/download/curl-7.47.1.tar.gz | tar xzv && \
cd curl-7.47.1; ./configure; make; make install; cd .. && \
wget -qO- https://cran.r-project.org/src/base/R-3/R-3.4.4.tar.gz | tar xzv && \
cd R-3.4.4; ./configure --with-readline=no --with-x=no && \
make; make install;cd .. && \
cd zlib-1.2.8; pwd; make uninstall; cd ..; rm -r /packages1/zlib-1.2.8 && \
pwd; cd pcre-8.35; pwd; make uninstall; cd ..;rm -r /packages1/pcre-8.35   && \
cd xz-5.2.2; pwd; make uninstall; cd ..; rm -r /packages1/xz-5.2.2; cd curl-7.47.1; pwd; make uninstall; cd ..; rm -r /packages1/curl-7.47$
Rscript -e 'install.packages("dplyr", repos="https://cloud.r-project.org/", dependencies=TRUE)' && \
#   Rscript -e 'remove.packages("dplyr", lib=/usr/local/lib64/R/library)' && \
Rscript -e 'install.packages("xml2", repos="https://cloud.r-project.org/")' && \
#    Rscript -e 'remove.packages("xml2", lib=/usr/local/lib64/R/library)' && \
Rscript -e 'install.packages("mongolite", repos="https://cloud.r-project.org/")' && \
#    Rscript -e 'remove.packages("mongolite", lib=/usr/local/lib64/R/library)' && \
Rscript -e 'install.packages("tidyr", repos="https://cloud.r-project.org/")' && \
#    Rscript -e 'remove.packages("tidyr", lib=/usr/local/lib64/R/library))' && \
Rscript -e 'install.packages("Rcpp", repos="https://cloud.r-project.org/")' && \
#    Rscript -e 'remove.packages("Rcpp", lib=/usr/local/lib64/R/library))' && \
Rscript -e 'install.packages("RcppEigen", repos="https://cloud.r-project.org/")' && \
#    Rscript -e 'remove.packages("RcppEigen", lib=/usr/local/lib64/R/library))' && \
Rscript -e 'install.packages("rstan", repos="https://cloud.r-project.org/")' && \
#    Rscript -e 'remove.packages("rstan", lib=/usr/local/lib64/R/library))' && \
Rscript -e 'install.packages("prophet", repos="https://cloud.r-project.org/")' && \
#    Rscript -e 'remove.packages("prophet", lib=/usr/local/lib64/R/library))' && \
Rscript -e 'install.packages("rjson", repos="https://cloud.r-project.org/")'  && \
#    Rscript -e 'remove.packages("rjson", lib=/usr/local/lib64/R/library))' && \
Rscript -e 'install.packages("stringi", repos="https://cloud.r-project.org/")' && \
#    Rscript -e 'remove.packages("stringi", lib=/usr/local/lib64/R/library))' && \
Rscript -e 'install.packages("stringr", repos="https://cloud.r-project.org/")' && \
yum remove -y devtoolset-6  && \
rm -rf /var/cache/yum && \
rm -rf /usr/local/lib64/R/library
RUN rm -rf /tmp
```

Comment: unless you share the docker file, I don't think any of us can do anything

Comment: Dockerfile added

Comment: How about using prebuilt images from `rocker` as base image? That way you don‘t have to compile R from source.

Comment: Hey @RalfStubner I need a specific version of R i.e R-3.4.4, If i use rocker base image I will get the latest version for R

Comment: @CharveePunia Not if you use `rocker/r-ver:3.4.4`.

Comment: wow, I thought we don't have that image. Trying it out :) also I think rocker is for ubuntu, I need a centos, do we have for centos too ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here some ideas that might help you:

The fastest installation would probably Ubuntu 18.04 as base together with the c4d2u PPA. That way you could install most (all?) R packages as binaries instead of installing them from source. IIRC there is even a Docker image from the `rocker` project that implements that idea. Another possibility would be `rocker/r-ver:3.4.4`, which is based on Debian.

If it has to be CentOS, you should enable EPEL. That way R 3.4.4 might be directly available. However, all the build dependencies for R are available as binaries, including a split between development and run-time packages. If you build R from source, you should use one `RUN` block which

- installs runtime and development dependencies
- downloads, configures and installs R
- deletes R sources and development packages

For package installation I would use a single `install.packages` with a suitable option `nCPU` (sp?) to enable parallel processing. Note that the final `rm -rf /tmp/*` should be part of the same `RUN` statement.

I would use two `RUN` statements, one for installing R and one for installing the packages. This should not increase the image size (segnificantly). But if you only change the list of packages, you do not have to reinstall R.